# std_vector.i doesn't wrap inherited classes correctly

Tags: c++, class, swig

In C++, I have a class ("BaseClass") and a class ("ClassA") which inherits from BaseClass. I use SWIG 3.0.2 to wrap my C++ stuff to C# and I use "std_vector.i" to enable "List" functionality in my C# application.

In the C++ function "CallCS", I create a list of two elements - the first is of class BaseClass and the second of ClassA. The list is made available to the C# application through a callback function. The interface file shows how I wrap the list.

However, iterating through the list in the C# application, I'm not able to access the ClassA element as a ClassA element though it is for sure a ClassA element (I simply cannot cast it in any way). I can access it only as if it was a BaseClass object.

Can anybody tell me if I miss something here ?

Here is my C++ .h file:

```
#include <vector>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    int m_x;
    BaseClass(int x): m_x(x) {}
    int GetX() { return m_x; }
};

class ClassA : public BaseClass
{
public:
    int m_y;
    ClassA(int x, int y) : BaseClass(x), m_y(y) {}
    int GetY() { return m_y; }
};

typedef std::vector<BaseClass*> BaseListType;

class Receiver
{
public:
    virtual void CallBack(BaseListType& list) {}
};

class Sender
{
public:
    Receiver* m_receiver;
public:
    Sender(Receiver* receiver) : m_receiver(receiver) {}
    void CallCS()
    {
        BaseListType list;
        list.push_back(new BaseClass(0));
        list.push_back(new ClassA(1, 2));
        m_receiver->CallBack(list);
    }
};
```

Here is my interface file:

```
%module(directors="1") example

%include <std_vector.i>

%feature("director") Receiver;

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"

%template(BaseListType) std::vector<BaseClass*>;
```

Here is my C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class runme
{
    class Subscriber : Receiver
    {
        public override void CallBack(BaseListType list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------ CallBack ...");
            Console.WriteLine("  Expectation:");
            Console.WriteLine("    First elem:  BaseClass");
            Console.WriteLine("    Second elem: ClassA");
            Console.WriteLine();
            var classalist = list.Select(x => x as ClassA).Where(x => x != null).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("  Count(ClassA) = " + classalist.Count() + ":");
            foreach (BaseClass elem in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    Is BaseClass: " + (elem is BaseClass) + " ... Is ClassA: " + (elem is ClassA));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------ CallBack done");
        }

        public void Run() 
        {
            Sender s = new Sender(this);
            s.CallCS();
        }
    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Subscriber s = new Subscriber();
        s.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a C++ issue (base* = derived*) than swig? Ideally you have to have a virtual BaseClass::GetY(). Or add a pure virtual type() to BaseClass & do if type() == THIS/THAT in your application code (Yikes! I know). The avoid dynamic_cast struggle we (at least me) always go through. No idea how casts are done in C# though.

Comment: Looks like your .Where() clause is excluding the element of BaseClass, because x as Class A will return null when it's an object of type BaseClass, so it never makes it into the list.

Comment: sambha, you are right ... it's a C++ issue. I am able to solve my problem using "%extend" in the interface file as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458025/how-to-properly-downcast-in-c-sharp-with-a-swig-generated-interface

Answer (score 0):

Can't test here but adding `virtual ~BaseClass() {}` to `BaseClass` will probably do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. However, I found a solution - see my comment to sambha.

Comment: Excellent. You should put your comment in an answer that shows how you applied technique from that post, then accept your answer so it gets closed. Thx!